# Node.js + static content served by Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, httpserver, app.yaml

The Google Cloud documentation isn't very precise on the available syntax for the *app.yaml* file used for my *Node.js* application.

I used the syntax described in the [Python documentation for GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers), from which I've found the *handlers* mecanism:

```
    handlers:
    - url: /index.html
      static_files: /public/index.html
      upload: /public/index.html
```

I've avoid my expressjs rule to serve the */public/index.html* content and finally I got a 404 error, meaning GAE is not serving my page as a static content:

```
    $ curl -i "http://my-project/index.html"
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    ...
```

Do you have any clue on this? Node.js is relevant for making APIs, generating dynamic content... But I prefer using the Google backends or even a Nginx server to handle static contents.

### Update

Removing the leading slashes didn't fixed the issue. I slightly changed my *app.yaml* configuration:

```
    handlers:
    - url: /api/.*
      secure: always
      script: app.js
    - url: /.*
      secure: always
      static_dir: public
```

And I still get **404 Not found** on `/index.html`, and getting
the correct **200 OK** answser when calling `/api/stuff`.

Here is my project tree structure:

```
    Project root
    |- app.js
    |- app.yaml
    |- package.json
    |- public/
    |  `-- css/
    |     `-- style.css
    |  `-- js/
    |     `-- main.js
    |  `-- index.html
```

Comment: Are you still having issues with `static_dir` static file handlers in app.yaml with the Nodejs runtime?  Was the answer provided by Dan effective (as it seems unclear from the comments)?

Answer (score 1):

The examples at the very documentation page should normally suffice.

You have a leading `/` in the `static_files` and `upload` values, which should be just relative paths to the top of your app dir.

There could be other reasons as well, the starting point would be the logs for your app, either on your development server or on GAE if already deployed.

Update:

According to the [Static directory handlers doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers):

> A static directory example:
>
> ```
> handlers:
> # All URLs beginning with /stylesheets are treated as paths to static files in
> # the stylesheets/ directory.
> - url: /stylesheets
>   static_dir: stylesheets
> ```
>
> url
>
> A URL prefix. This value uses regular expression syntax (and so regexp
>   special characters must be escaped), but it should not contain
>   groupings. All URLs that begin with this prefix are handled by this
>   handler, using the portion of the URL after the prefix as part of the
>   file path.

Based on this quote I'd suspect the wildcards in the `url` of the `app.yaml`'s handler spec may be causing issues (for example the `/index.html` *might* actually be expanded to `/index.html/` by the `static_dir` parsing logic), I'd replace the url to clearly indicate a directory, like this:

```
- url: /
  secure: always
  static_dir: public
```

I'm not a fan of tying the top level `/` of the app's namespace to a static dir, but it may be OK for a generally static app. Make sure you always keep this handler spec last in your `app.yaml` file to avoid issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I dropped my leading `/`, but nothing changed. I get this error, meaning the handler has been parsed but still the file cannot be found: `Static file referenced by handler not found: public/index.html`

Comment: Please edit the question adding the directory structure of your project to show where the `index.html` file resides.

Comment: I've set up your handler with only one "/", and it's still not working. I still got errors: "Static file referenced by handler not found: public/", "Static file referenced by handler not found: public/index.html", and "Static file referenced by handler not found: public/index.html/" when I request respectively "/", "/index.html", "/index.html/". Do you have any clue? Do you know how to report a bug to the Google developers? Thanks!

Comment: You still have the url as `/.*`, not `/`.

Comment: No its not. I'm using the / in my handlers:
- url: /
  secure: always
  static_dir: public

Comment: My suspicion was confirmed last night, see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447890/static-files-are-missing/33448239#33448239