# Static files are missing

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, yaml

In my app there is a `/static` folder which contains all the static resources needed by the app. Here is my handlers for the static resources:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

This works for files directly in `/static`, but let's say I also have another folder containing jQuery:

```
static
  |- jquery
  |   \- jquery.js
  |
  \- images
      \- ...
```

When I try to reach `[myapp].appspot.com/static/jquery/jquery.js` it would return a 404 and I have no idea why.

Also some of my files including `.css` and `.ttf` etc. are giving me a `Could not guess mimtype` error. I have no idea how to solve that.

---

## Edit

Added my (new) app.yaml. I don't have a dispatch.yaml.

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static/pages_style
  mime_type: text/css
  static_dir: /static/pages_style

- url: /static/images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/images/\1
  upload: static/images/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /static/bootstrap 3.3.5
  static_dir: /static/bootstrap 3.3.5

- url: /static/jquery 2.1.4
  static_dir: /static/jquery 2.1.4
    
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: for the mimetype error see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425364/could-not-guess-mimetype

Comment: @DanCornilescu Do you know what is causing the 404 problem?

Comment: Unclear yet. The `static_dir` should work recursively as well (assuming the path is correct), something else is going on. Can you pls post your entire content of your `.yaml` module files and that of the `dispatch.yaml` file (if you use one)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Added to the question. I don't have a `dispatch.yaml` file.

Comment: Aha. I bet the `/static/(.*\.css)$` `static_files` routing conflicts with the `/static` `static_dir` one. Try to make them non-overlapping, for example change `/static` to be more specific, like `/static/jquery`, move the `.css` files to a `css` subdir side by side with `jquery`, so that you can change `/static/(.*\.css)$` to `/static/css/(.*\.css)$`. You'll need similar stuff to address the mimetype error anyways.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I've changed all of them (updated above) to be more specific now but it's giving me a 404... One thing I noticed though, is that the images/html always work. Other than those, like .css and .js none of them works. (And now my local server is also serving 404... I don't know what I did wrong)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93848/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-derek-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `404` errors on `[myapp].appspot.com/static/jquery/jquery.js` requests were caused by a `static_files` URL pattern being under a `static_dir` URL path:

```
- url: /static/(.*\.css)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)$

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

In the above example `/static/(.*\.css)$` matches are located under `/static`. I guess the static dir/files routing in the GAE infra gets confused in such cases.

The solution is to make the paths more specific such that the `static_dir` URLs never include paths matching `static_files` URL patterns or other `static_dir` URLs.

About the `Could not guess mimetype` error, this Q&A explains it well: [Could not guess mimetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425364/could-not-guess-mimetype)