# Retrieving default fallback avatar image using python and GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

my users can upload an image of themselves and use that as an avatar. Now I am struggling how to retrieve a default fallback image if they haven't uploaded an image themselves.

The path to the avatar is "//mysite.com/avatar/username".

So far I have this code, which works fine when the user has uploaded an avatar themselves, but it gives me the following error when I try to retrieve the default image:

> raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
>
> IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Users/myuser/Documents/github/mysite/static/images/profile.png'

```
def get(self):
    path = self.request.path.split('/')
    action = self.get_action(path)

    if action:
        e = employees.filter('username = ', action).get()

        if e.avatar:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            self.response.out.write(e.avatar)
        else:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
            path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'static/images/profile.png')
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                print self.response.out.write(f.read())
```

I have defined the "/static"-folder as a static_dir in my app.yaml.

I know I can place the profile.png in the root-folder, but I prefer to have it in the "/static/images"-folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you check the value of `path` variable?

Comment: yes. it resolves the path to the correct path. I updated the question above to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the file itself as a `static_file` or its directory or any directory in its filepath a `static_dir` inside your app/service's `.yaml` config file then, by default, it's not accessible to the application code.

You need to also configure it as `application_readable`. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element):

> application_readable
>
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file handlers
>   are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users. They
>   cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the
>   files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read
>   them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data
>   storage [resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code).

Comment: are there any drawbacks to enabling setting application_readable?

Comment: AFAIK just counting them twice in the files quota and longer deployment times as they're uploaded twice.

Comment: thanks. Do you know if I can put application_readable on a subdirectory? Eg. put application_readable on /static/images but not for other directories and files in /static?

Comment: Theoretically yes, if you add a separate handler definition for `/static/images` above the one for `/static` you could configure them differently. But I did see reports of some problems which *might* be related to nested static dir/files (just a suspicion, no proof). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447890/static-files-are-missing