# app.yaml settings for uploading static files

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine, static, app.yaml

I'm facing issues with `app.yaml` settings of my Python App Engine web application. Somehow except index.html rest of the static files (javascript, CSS and HTML) which I have in my application are not getting deployed to the app engine. I have tried variety of combinations of `static_files` and `upload` elements under script in `app.yaml`. Though some of them work on local dev app server, they do not work when deployed on app engine via `gcloud app deploy`. Logs produced by the gcloud do not show any errors. They show DEBUG messages like "Skipping upload of [...]" for all my static files.

Directory structure of the application (it's an AngularJS application) is as follows:

```
<APP ROOT>
├── app.yaml
├── my_scripts
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── ...
├── index.html
├── mainapp.py
└── web
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │   │   ├── ....
    │   │   └── ....
    │   └── js
    │       ├── app
    │       │   ├── app.js
    │       │   └── ....
    │       └── lib
    │           └── ...
    └── partials
        ├── login.html
        └── ...
```

Following is the app.yml file for my application.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /(user|tasks)/.*
  script: mainapp.app

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /web
  static_files: web\/[^\n]*
  upload: web\/[^\n]*

- url: /web
  static_dir: web
```

Any pointers to help me fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447890/static-files-are-missing/33448239#33448239. See if addressing that problem helps with the static files being skipped during deployment. BTW - is there a reason for skipping them displayed anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You have the change the routing order. That is, `/web` should come just before to the `/` handler so that the GAE routing will look for `/web` at first and then it goes for `/` (note down the order top to bottom). If you define `/` before `/web`, it always shows the `index.html` file since `/` will also match `/web`.

```
handlers:

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /(user|tasks)/.*
  script: mainapp.app

- url: /web
  static_dir: web

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

And also I hope you haven't add `^web` to the `skip_files` section in `app.yaml`

Comment: Actually `/` won't match `/web`, you may be thinking at `/.*` or just `.*`?

Comment: Regex / should return a match object against the string /web

Comment: A `search` object yes, but not a `match` one (in python `re` talk). Try it out on an actual GAE project.

Answer (score 1):

The following handler configuration has worked for me:

```
- url: /(user|tasks)/.*
  script: mainapp.app

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /web
  static_files: web/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
  upload: web/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)

- url: /web
  static_dir: web
```

Comment: So you're saying that both `/web/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `/web/assets/js/app/app.js` are uploaded with this config?