# Deploy static website getting 404 Not Found - gcloud app browse

Tags: google-app-engine, web-deployment, gcloud

i am trying to deploy/ host a static website on gcloud following the web tutorial blogs available.
Connected gcloud sdk
changed directory to the sample-app (website + app.yaml)
used command `gcloud app deploy`
Files get uploaded & service gets deployed.
[image: gcloud console]

But on hitting the web address

[image: The URL says...]

App engine Dashboard says there are Client Errors

[image]

Content in app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: website/index.html
  upload: website/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: website
```

Comment: Need to see the url handlers in your app.yaml.

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Your log shows `Uploading 0 files...`, so something is misconfigured. You need to show your config files.

Comment: added app.yaml content as asked @GAEfan 
will take care of not posting text as image next time.

Comment: Can you show the content of the `AlphaX` directory, including file permissions?

Comment: Try to temporarily comment out the 1st handler section and change in the 2nd one the url from `/` to `.*`.  Then explicitly try to access the `/index.html` path or some other path. Sometimes overlapping `static_dir` and `static_files` paths/patterns can cause trouble, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447890/static-files-are-missing/33448239#33448239