# App Engine - app.yaml handler for images

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I'm trying to understand app.yaml a little better.

GCP docs recommend creating a handler for your images like this:

```
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true
```

However I use the much simpler:

```
- url: /assets/images
  static_dir: assets/images
```

I would like to understand the extra parameters and regular expressions Google has used.

What are the differences between Google's and my handler?

PS at the moment my handler is working, but when I use the Google handler my images do not load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is in the `static_files` row from the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

> **static_files**
>
> Optional. A static file pattern handler associates a URL pattern with
>   paths to static files uploaded with the application. The URL pattern
>   regular expression can define regular expression groupings to be used
>   in the construction of the file path. You can use this instead of
>   **static_dir** to map to specific files in a directory structure without mapping the entire directory.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> handlers:
> # All URLs ending in .gif .png or .jpg are treated as paths to
> # static files in the static/ directory. The URL pattern is a
> # regular expression, with a grouping that is inserted into the
> # path to the file.
> - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
>   static_files: static/\1
>   upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
> ```

The `url` is the requested path while `static_files` and `upload` are real file paths relative to your app/service source directory, with `\1` and `.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$` respectively replaced by the url regex matching grouping value - whatever is inside the outer round paranthesis.

So a request to `/a_file.gif` will match the `url` regex, producing a `a_file.gif` grouping. Which will be replaced into `static_files` and `upload` as `static/a_file.gif` - the actual path of the file in your app source code.

With your `static_dir` config **any** file that exists under `assets/images` would be served if a matching request to `/assets/images/<the_file>` is made, regardles of what that filename is.

With a `static_files` config you can select only specific filenames to be served (that match the regex pattern) and you can make them appear with a different name and/or in a different path than the one where they really are relative to the app dir.

Your `static_files` config *should* be working if you make requests to the right path, like `/assets/images/<some_file>.png` for example (I assume that's where your image files exist).

But if you want, for example, to serve a file located under that `assets/images` dir but requested simply as `/<some_file>.png` (i.e. without that path prefix) you'd need to configure it differently:

```
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: assets/images/\1
  upload: assets/images/.+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

Also check that you don't have overlapping `static_dir` and/or `static_files` paths configured - that can cause obscure problems, see [Static files are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447890/static-files-are-missing/33448239#33448239)