# Google App Engine API + static architecture

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, web-applications, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying to (con)figure the best way to structure a JS client + NodeJS server app to host it on Google Cloud AppEngine (plus possibly other GCP resources).  So I'm looking for advice / best practices here.

We have an API server running on a non-default AppEngine service and would like to be able to run several, e.g. development/staging/production versions on the same project (if possible).

We would like to host / serve our static client app on this system because we want to use the same domain to point at it.

In our normal server based setup, the client app is proxied/served on `domain.com/` and requests to the API are on `domain.com/v1/`

I've been working through different options - hosting a separate static site running on AppEngine and using `dispatch.yaml` to try to route requests - this option doesn't seem to work with domain prefixes, only wildcards, e.g.

```
dispatch:
- url: "my-client-service-project.appspot.com/"
  service: my-client-service
- url: "my-client-service-project.appspot.com/v1/*"
  service: my-backend-service
```

Doesn't work, but:

```
- url: "*/v1/*"
  service: my-backend-service
```

Does, which we didn't want because we'd like to run **dev**, **staging** & **production** if possible.

The other option I've been looking at is having the static folder hosted as part of my app, but I can't seem to get this working either, here is the snippet from my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    static_files: client/dist/index.html
    upload: frontend/dist/index.html
  - url: /v1/*
    script: dist/index.js
```

My guess is that `script` may not work the same as for Python apps, but I could be wrong - the doc's aren't very clear.

Ideally, I'd like to host the client front-end static files on storage and point to the AppEngine API server (without specifically pointing to a domain from the client, e.g. `/v1/auth/login` rather than `my-backend-service-project.appspot.com/v1/`

References:

[How can I use bucket storage to serve static files on google flex/app engine environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631414/how-can-i-use-bucket-storage-to-serve-static-files-on-google-flex-app-engine-env)

[Node.js + static content served by Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300320/node-js-static-content-served-by-google-app-engine)

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin: you're mixing up standard and flexible env docs - not a good idea as they don't work the same way. See [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or).

Since your app is Node.JS you have to use the flexible env, for which `script` and `static_files` aren't applicable inside `app.yaml`. Which is why you can't get them to work.

The first reference in your list shows the options you have for serving the static files. But I kinda question your desire to use the shared GCS option - it will serve the same content regardless of the dev/staging/production environment, so:

- you can't have different client side environments
- how do you see selecting a particular server-side environment since the client side references can only point in one direction (i.e. environment, if I understand your intention correctly)?

If your desire to use a single domain means that you'd still be OK with using different subdomains (of that domain) and if you'd be willing to use a custom domain this *might* be of interest: [How to use GAE's dispatch.yaml with multiple development environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016022/how-to-use-gaes-dispatch-yaml-with-multiple-development-environments?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**UPDATE:**

Node.JS is currently available in the standard environment as well, so you can use those features, see:

- [Now, you can deploy your Node.js app to App Engine standard environment](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/Now-you-can-deploy-your-Node-js-app-to-App-Engine-standard-environment.html)
- [Google App Engine Node.js Standard Environment Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the answer.  Yes, ultimately we want to use a sub-domain e.g. dev.mydomain.com and prod.mydomain.com, so initially (looking at your linked answer) we would have services in the same project and consider splitting out into multiple projects after.

For serving the client app, we considered deploying different client apps to different GCS buckets / folders, so they would all point to dev / prod servers (as opposed to using express to serve, etc).  I then struggled with whether could 'mask' the GCS domain with dev-mydomain.com somehow (without another proxy container, etc)?

Comment: Aah, maybe speaking too soon - cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website shows me how to point at the GCS bucket, so I guess I'd need to do: `client-site.mydomain.com -> GCS bucket AND api.mydomain.com -> GAE prod.service (POSSIBLY WITH) client-dev.mydomain.com -> Another GCS bucket (or app config) dev-api.mydomain.com -> GAE dev.service` Need to look at that...

Answer (score 2):

Take this answer as a complement to the one of @Dan Corneliscu, as I think it is pretty useful and summarizes what you are doing wrong and what can be achieved in the type of scenario you present. In any case, I would like to provide some more information which may be useful.

As for the reason why the *dispatch rules* approach you suggested does not work, you should update your paths in the application accordingly. They should now be listening to `/v1/your_endpoint` instead of `/your_endpoint` as they probably did before. It is not enough with changing your *dispatch* file. Then also make sure that the *Dispatch routes* field is populated in your [App Engine > Services tab](http://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services) in the Console.

Also the alternative approach you suggested will indeed not work using `static_files`, but you can follow this guide explaining [how to serve Static Files from a GAE Flexible application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I will look at where I'm listening and see if that helps (yeah, I've seen the Dispatch routes populated for previous experiments).  I've looked into the options in that document, but the thing it glosses over (which I've mentioned above) is how do I point a (sub-)domain at both the service and the front-end in GCS.  I've a feeling it can't be done in GAE without additional proxies / config running somewhere else.